# Juntar os spans com display::inline-block igual como com float:left

Tags: css, css3

```css
 div.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 div.dropdown span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 div.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 195px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }
 
 div.dropdown:hover 
 div.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
 }
 
 div.dropdown:hover 
 div.dropdown-content p{
  width: 195px;
  height: 30px; 
  line-height: 30px; 
 }
 
 div.dropdown:hover 
 div.dropdown-content p:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class=dropdown>
 <span>Cadastros</span>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p id='cadastrarMembro'>Cadastrar Membro</p>
  <p id='cadastrarAdministrador'>Cadastrar Administrador</p>
  <p id='cadastrarCeldiva'>Cadastrar Gcéu</p>
  <p id='cadastrarCeldivaMembro'>Cadastrar Membro no Gcéu</p>
  <p id='cadastrarMensagem'>Cadastrar Mensagem</p>
  <p id='cadastrarEstudo'>Cadastrar Estudo</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class=dropdown>
 <span>Edições</span>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p id='alterarMembro'>Alterar Membro</p>
  <p id='alterarAdministrador'>Alterar Administrador</p>
  <p id='alterarCeldiva'>Alterar Gcéu</p>
  <p id='alterarCeldivaMembro'>Alterar Membro em Gcéu</p>
  <p id='alterarMensagem'>Alterar Mensagem</p>
  <p id='alterarEstudo'>Alterar Estudo</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class=dropdown>
 <span>Cadastros</span>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p id='lancarReuniaoCeldiva'>Reunião no Gcéu</p>
  <p id='relatorio'>Relatórios</p>
  <p id='email'>E-mails</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Percebam que entre os spans existe um espaço.

Como fazer para colar os **spans** com `display: inline-block` igual como com `float:left`

Comment: Na verdade vc não quer juntar os spans, mas sim as divs onde estão os spans :D

Comment: sim. sim, isso mesmo. O objetivo é retirar os espaços entre essas divs para ficar todas juntas